# Perl : ignore columns from csv file during insert

Tags: oracle, perl

I'm inserting a CSV file into TAB,

Is there any way I can ignore 2nd and 3rd column from the CSV file during insert?

I tried changing $row[] values to $row[0],$row[3],$row[4],$row[5],$row[6] but this doesn't work. Tried few more things and also search inside SO but couldn't find what I'm looking for.

could somebody suggest or point me to link?

```
use warnings;    
use strict;
use Text::CSV;
use DBD::Oracle;

my $exitStatus = 0;

dbConnect();
&insertRecords
#----------------
sub insertRecords {
 my $csv;
 my $fileToInsert = shift;
 my $row;
 my $SQL1;
 my $sth;
 my $rc; 

 open my $fh, "<", $fileToInsert or die "$filetoInsert: $!"

 $SQL1 = "Insert into TAB1 (sample_date, server, first, n1, n2)
         values (?,?,?,?,?)";
 $sth = prepare($SQL1)

while ($row = $csv->getline ($fh)) {
    $sth -> execute($row[0], $row[1], $row[2], $row[3], $row[4])
}


CSV File:
sample_date,
date_x1
x2
server
first
n1
n2
```

Comment: @DVK , sure don't mind your edits as different person see things differently. Starting my questions with friends was more of a polite way for request rather than being rude and directly post my problem.

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior, the section on "Do not use signature, taglines, or greetings". Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to first read the whole file ,then run the query.

Right now the query is run on every line. But you have each entry one a line - not per column as you write - so you might not need the CSV module? Anyway, there are several errors in there. I've simplified it a little.

try something like this:

```
use warnings;    
use strict;
use DBD::Oracle;

my $exitStatus = 0;

dbConnect();
my $file = shift;
&insertRecords($file);

#----------------

sub insertRecords {
  my $fileToInsert = shift;
  my $fh;

  open $fh, "<", $fileToInsert or die "$fileToInsert: $!";

  my $SQL1 = "Insert into TAB1 (sample_date, server, first, n1, n2) values (?,?,?,?,?)";
  my $sth = prepare($SQL1);

  my @row = $fh->getlines;
  print ($row[0], $row[3], $row[4], $row[5], $row[6]); # <-- always good for testing!

  $sth -> execute($row[0], $row[3], $row[4], $row[5], $row[6]);

}
```

Comment: thanks for your comments and suggestions, I'm using CSV modules, but didn't listed since I was more concentrating on how to exclude columns. I tried to limit length of my code and details to keep it short.

Comment: yes, just now I tested it and work perfectly fine. Not sure why it didn't worked earlier with similar approach. Print suggestion also helped in confirming value at runtime.